# Refactoring static classes and methods (Json serialisation/deserialisation)

Tags: c#, json.net

I've used https://quicktype.io to create a class for my Json data. However I'm not really understanding why with the helper methods created to convert to json, from json, and supply default parameters they are each created differently as a static method of the class, a static class and a class with a static method.

The reason really is because as soon as I create a second class from another set of json data the code fails because of the static classes and I want to make sure I refactor them correctly. As well as understand the reasons of course.

I figure 'Converter' will never change across all my json objects so I can move this as is to a separate file and Serialize to a static method with FromJson. But I'd just like to understand more about the reasoning of how it was done in the first place and the better approach.

Here is the code:

```
public partial class StationDO
{
    public string Active { get; set; }
    //more fields here
}

public partial class StationDO
    {
        public static List<StationDO> FromJson(string json)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StationDO>>(json, Converter.Settings);
        }
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this List<StationDO> self)
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, Converter.Settings);
        }
    }

    public class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
        };
    }
```

If I look at the Java code the same site produces, it simply puts everything bar the bean into a single class 'Converter'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have all the static members in `StationDO` class. In that case I recommend mark that class as sealed (`public sealed class StationDO`) to prevent someone to inheriting from that class and use the static methods from inherited class.

```
public class InheritedStationDO : StationDO { }
// ... somewhere else ...
InheritedStationDO.FromJson(jsonValue); // still returns List<StationDO> not List<InheritedStationDO> !!!
```

**EDIT:**

After close look I think, the whole design of members is not good.

1) There is no need to accept just `List<StationDO>`.

2) There is no need the defined special methods for (de)serialization of every class, you will have. You can have just one method for serialization and one for deserialization for all your classes.

**Example:**

```
public class StationDO {
    public string Active { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherDO {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// and more *DO classes

// class need to be "static" because contains "extension methods"
public static class MySerializationHelper {
    private static readonly JsonSerializerSettings serializationSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
        };

    // universal method for deserialization from json
    // the generic type "T" represents the result type of deserialization
    public static T FromJson<T>(string json) {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json, serializationSettings);
    }

    // universal method for serialization to json
    // this "this" keyword means, its "extension method"
    public static string ToJson<T>(this T self) {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, serializationSettings);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
StationDO obj01 = GetSomeStation();

// returns json of one object
string json01A = obj01.ToJson(); // these two lines are equivalent
string json01B = MySerializationHelper.ToJson(obj01); // these two lines are equivalent

// returns new object deserialized from json in "json01" variable
StationDO clone01 = MySerializationHelper.FromJson<StationDO>(json01A);

StationDO obj02 = GetAnotherStation();
StationDO[] arr01 = new StationDO[] { obj01, obj02 };

// returns json of array with two objects
string json02A = arr01.ToJson(); // these two lines are equivalent
string json02B = MySerializationHelper.ToJson(arr01); // these two lines are equivalent

// returns new array with deserialized object from json in "json02" variable
StationdDO[] clone02 = MySerializationHelper.FromJson<StationdDO[]>(json02A);

AnotherDO obj03 = GetAnotherDO();
string json03A = obj03.ToJson(); // these two lines are equivalent
string json03B = MySerializationHelper.ToJson(obj03); // these two lines are equivalent
```

As you see, the generics is the way, how to avoid code duplication for every class.
And you can (de)serialize all kind of arrays and collections or single objects. Not just `List<T>`.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I'm just trying to understand better the logic behind why these three things were done as they were? At first I thought 'Serialize' was some kind of magic name that json.net or .net used...

Comment: When I do that I get 'Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class'. So I can't really make the whole class static as I might have more than one StationDO?

Comment: In .net is very low magic names, usually you don't even need to know them. Technically, in this case aren't nested classes necessary. Maybe the "Serialize" class is there for some syntax sugar purpose allowing you write "StationDO.Serialize.ToJson(myList)".

Comment: @TcKs Serialize is not a nested class there.

Comment: Oh, I watched over the "this" keyword. That means, it is extension method, I will expand the answer.

Comment: No worries, I saw it too and removed 'this' and it worked. I guess I'm new to 'extension' methods :)

Comment: Extension methods are super-simple, and you will meet them all the time. Don't worry about them :).

Comment: That works and is superb. Not only makes it easier to use the website as I simply copy the code and remove the methods, but my hack for testing if it was an array or not ("[") and looping through a list is all gone :)

One typo, in case anyone reads this, you've left in 'Converter.Settings' in the bottom method and needs changing to serializationSettings

Comment: Thanks for typo notice. I'm glad, it helped you.

Comment: quicktype generates the helper methods in partial static classes to keep the models simple, but we may reconsider this.

ToJson is defined as an extension method because it has to work on all JSON types, including arrays, maps, and primitive values. For example, you might want to call ToJson on a `string[]`, so this has to be an extension.